# How do i increment during a Do-While loop?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
do {


    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"wcqQuestionText"]) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
        label.text = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
        [label release];
        [formulierText removeFromSuperview];

    }

    // if the element has child elements, process them
    if (element->firstChild) 
        [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

    // Obtain next sibling element
} while ((element = element->nextSibling));
```

Each time a label has been written, i want the next label to be positioned under the label that has just been created. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create float variable to track y position of label's frame and increase it each time label is added (you'll also need to adjust scroll's contentSize if all labels do not fit its frame):

```
static CGFloat y = 100.0f;

do {

    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"wcqQuestionText"]) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, y, 200, 100)];
        label.text = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
        [label release];
        [formulierText removeFromSuperview];
        y += 100.0f;
    }

    // if the element has child elements, process them
    if (element->firstChild) 
        [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

    // Obtain next sibling element
} while ((element = element->nextSibling));
```

P.S. Have you considered using standard UITableView instead of self-tailored UIScrollView?

Comment: I can't make an UITableView. I need to build up a form of different elements, including these labels. I just had shortened the code for the purpose of demonstrating.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work. It just writes all the labels on top of each other. So i only see the last label written.

Comment: @Jack, I've edited an answer making y variable static - so it will keep its value between method calls (necessary if you call your method recursively). However, it may be better to parse whole xml to some array and then create labels from that array (if you're going to use those strings later)

Comment: And i wanted it to reset each time the loop will run.. How do i do that?

Comment: @Jack, for example if you have some unique root element in xml you can reset 'y' if your method currently parses that root element

Comment: Thanks! I got a root node which is called: formdata. When it reaches this, the y = 100.0f again. Thank you for the tip!